# Android: Don't rotate the screen of the activity (No Manifest)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screen

I know that I have to use android:screenOrientation="portrait/landscape" if I want to not change the rotation of the screen, but I do this in the Manifest. I want to do the same thing in the java class. How can I do this?

This is my code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo, container, false);
                return rootView;

            case 2:
                View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo2, container, false);
                return rootView2;

            case 3:
                View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo3, container, false);
                return rootView3;

            case 4:
                View rootView4 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo4, container, false);
                return rootView4;

            default:
                View rootView0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cubo, container, false);
                return rootView0;
        }
    }
```

And I want to change the position of the screen only in the case 2 and 3, but I can't recall the method `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORT‌​RAIT);`

because it can't be referenced from a static context (the method onCreateView is in a class static)

How can I do this?

Comment: Try something like setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by below function

```
 public void changeOrientation() {

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your "getActivity()" helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

---

Great blog post on the subject here: https://www.novoda.com/blog/portrait-only-apps/ :-)

---

You should not really update questions, but ask new questions.

You need to override a callback method that has an activity param, or save the param as a field. So you might have to run the switch statement twice.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // your switch statement  
   activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

You can read up on it more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: When do I have to call the method onCreateView? I'm using a TabbedActivity. And what parameters do I have to pass? Nay, what LayoutInflater do I have to pass?

Comment: oh sorry, you mean `onCreateView` is the overridden method of a Fragment. Updated my answer

Comment: when I recall the method of the superclass `super.onAttach(Context context)`, what context do I have to pass?

Comment: pass the `activity`

Comment: that method rotates all the fragments, not only the second and the third.

Comment: In the method onAttach (Activity activity) I put a switch(...) {case 2: change rotation ... ... ...}

Comment: yes because rotation is Activity based, not fragment based. If you want to "rotate" a fragment, you will have to use a different feature

Comment: How do I use a different feature?

Comment: How do I use a different feature?

Comment: if you want to "change the orientation" of a fragment, you might be better just creating two fragments and swapping them out with the FragmentManager

Comment: How can I do this in code? Sorry but I'm a beginner

Comment: it's a big topic: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: How can I set the orientation of a fragment?